# meanshift clustering using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, pandas-groupby, user-defined-functions

We're trying to migrate a vanilla python code-base to pyspark. The agenda is to do some filtering on a dataframe (previously pandas, now spark), then group it by user-ids, and finally apply [meanshift](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) clustering on top.

I'm using `pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)` on the grouped-data. But now there's a problem in the way the final output should be represented.

Let's say we have two columns in the input dataframe, `user-id` and `location`. For each user we need to get all clusters (on the `location`), retain only the biggest one,  and then return its attributes, which is a 3-dimensional vector. Let's assume the columns of the 3-tuple are `col-1`, `col-2` and `col-3`. I can only think of creating the original dataframe with 5 columns, with these 3 fields set to `None`, using something like `withColumn('col-i', lit(None).astype(FloatType()))`. Then, in the first row for each user, I'm planning to populate these three columns with these attributes. But this seems really ugly way of doing it, and it would unnecessarily waste a lot of space, because apart from the first row, all entries in  `col-1`, `col-2` and `col-3` would be zero. The output dataframe would look something like below in this case:

```
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| user-id | location | col-1 | col-2 | col-3 |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 02751a9 | 0.894956 |  21.9 |  31.5 |  54.1 |
| 02751a9 | 0.811956 |  null |  null |  null |
| 02751a9 | 0.954956 |  null |  null |  null |
|                     ...                    |
| 02751a9 | 0.811956 |  null |  null |  null |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 0af2204 | 0.938011 |  11.1 |  12.3 |  53.3 |
| 0af2204 | 0.878081 |  null |  null |  null |
| 0af2204 | 0.933054 |  null |  null |  null |
| 0af2204 | 0.921342 |  null |  null |  null |
|                     ...                    |
| 0af2204 | 0.978081 |  null |  null |  null |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

This feels so wrong. Is there an elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, was grouped the df by user-ids, applied `functions.collect_list` on the columns, so that each cell contains a list. Now each user has only one row. Then I applied meanshift clustering on each row's data.